# Iterating a dataList in jsp using scriptlets

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

I would like to ask on how can I iterate a dataList in jsp using scriptlets given the code below. I know it is recommended to use jstl however, I am required to use scriplets in my activity. Please help, thanks!

```
<%@taglib uri="/WEB-INF/dlTagLib.tld" prefix="dl"%>
<%@page language="java"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Book Lists</title>   
</head>
<%    
    DataList bookDataList = (DataList) request.getAttribute("bookData");
%>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Author</td>
        </tr>
        <dl:iterate dataList = "${bookDataList}">
            <tr>
                <td><dl:get dataList = "${bookDataList}" column="book_title"/></td>
                <td><dl:get dataList = "${bookDataList}" column="book_author"/></td>
            </tr>
        </dl:iterate>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: This code won't work because `bookDataList` is a Java variable and `${bookDataList}` will search an attribute with name `"bookDataList"` in `pageContext`, `request`, `session` and `servletContext`. Since it cannot find that attribute (at least from what you show in your code) then nothing will be displayed. And you're not using JSTL here, expression language only. Still, I don't support scriptlets Q/As.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I know the code above wont work because I don't know how, that's why I'm seeking for the appropriate answer sir. Just like I said I know it is recommended to use jstl but it is REQUIRED to use scriptlets with regards to the given activity

Comment: *I know the code above wont work because I don't know how* I already explained why it won't work by any mean. And it's not so hard to port it to scriptlets...

Answer (score 0):

This is how the code may be using scriptlets with some assumptions:

- `DataList` extends or implements `List` or `Collection` or at least `Iterable`.
- You're using Java 5 or superior.
- The objects in `bookDataList` are of type `Data` or something like that
- This class `Data` has proper getters for the data you want/need.

```html
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <th>
            <td>Title</td>
            <td>Author</td>
        </th>
        <%
            DataList bookDataList = (DataList) request.getAttribute("bookData");
            for (Data book : bookDataList) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= book.getBook_Title() %></td>
            <td><%= book.getBook_Author() %></td>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </table>
</body>
```

If any of the assumptions above is incorrect, please specify it in your question to fix the code in this post.